# How to resolve "mongodb.driver" error in SSIS package

Tags: c#, mongodb, ssis

when i am running SSIS package getting this error:

Script Component has encountered an exception in user code:
Project Name: SC_76bc556b4d8343218e4abc8e9ea1e53
Could not load file or assembly 'Mongo.Driver' version=1.8.3.9, culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=f686731cfb9cc103' or one of its dependencies
The system can not find the file specified.

However i followed this article to create package:https://rajendersehgal.wordpress.com/2015/07/14/data-migration-between-mssql-nosql/

I am using windows 10 and placed Mongodb.driver.dll, Mongodb. Bson.dll in the assembly folder and then added reference by browsing both files in the framework.

Any advice is appreciable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to solve that you need to put mongo drivers into GAC repository, [see reference](http://arcanecode.com/2014/01/14/importing-mongodb-data-using-ssis-2012/) (you can encounter other issues as there maybe requirement for strong signature)

> First, download and install the C# driver. This next step is
>   important, as there was a change that occurred with version 1.5 of the
>   driver: the DLLs are no longer installed in the GAC (Global Assembly
>   Cache) automatically. They must be there, however, for SSIS to be able
>   to use them.
>
> By default, my drivers were installed to C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MongoDB\CSharpDriver 1.7. You’ll want to open a CMD window in
>   Administrator mode, and navigate to this folder. Next you’ll need
>   GACUTIL, on my computer I found the most recent version at:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1
>   Tools\x64\
>
> A simple trick to find yours: Since you are already in the CMD window,
>   just move to the C:\Program Files (x86) folder, and do a “dir /s
>   gacutil.exe”. It will list all occurrences of the program, just use
>   the one with the most recent date. Register the dlls by entering these
>   commands:
>
> “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1
>   Tools\x64\gacutil” /i MongDB.Bson.dll
>
> “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1
>   Tools\x64\gacutil” /i MongDB.Driver.dll
>
> Note the “ quote marks around the path are important for the CMD
>   window to correctly separate the gacutil program from the parameters.
>
> Once that is done, create a new SQL Server Integration Services
>   project in SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT), what used to be called BIDS
>   in SQL Server 2008R2 (and previous). Put a Data Flow Task on the
>   Control Flow design surface. Then open the Data Flow Task for editing.
>
> Next, drag and drop a Script Component transformation onto the Data
>   Flow design surface. When prompted, change the component type to
>   Source.